# Is there anyway to speed up or replace the Sense UI dialer?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-sense, droid-eris

I have a droid eris running android 2.1...the dialer for it is awful.  I dont know why they chose to put the end call button and send call button in the exact same area.  It is also very laggy.  Sometimes I will try to call someone and the send button gets hit twice which will initiate the call and then end it immediately.  Is there anyway to speed up or replace the Sense UI dialer?

Note:  I do not wish to completely remove my sense ui...only the dialer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few replacement dialer apps in the market - just search for 'Dialer'.

There are quite a few, both paid and free.  I've only tried one (*Dialer One*) just to confirm that it can indeed replace the default dialer, but I don't think it's sensible to go into any particular dialer's merits here.